# Variable outside foreach loop php

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach

I got a problem.

On Wordpress I define a foreach loop, to get some informations from attached image like title, description, etc...

Outside this loop, I want to call the result of various variables. How can I get `$attachment_description`, `$attachment_caption` and `$attachment_title` outside my loop?

Thanks for your help. Below the code :

```
if ( $attachments ) : 

echo $before;
    foreach( $attachments as $ID ){
        $attachment = get_post($ID);
        $attachment_description = $attachment->post_content; //Display description
        $attachment_caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; //Display caption
        $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title; //Display title

        //IF : Affichage sur certaines images
        //if($attachment_description != ''){
        //echo '<div class="item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolioslider' ) . '<div class="captionportfolio"><h1 class="titrecaption">' . $attachment_title . '</h1>' . $attachment_description . '</div></div>';
        //}// else {
        echo '<div class="item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolioslider' ) . '</div>';
        //}
    }
echo $after;

endif;
```

Nothings seems to works, this is the first file with the loop :

```
<?php 
/**
 * Make sure we can access post data easily.
 */
global $post;

/**
 * Setup variables needed for the gallery
 */
$attachments = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ebor_portfolio_gallery_list', true );
$type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ebor_gallery_format', true );
$before = '<div class="owl-carousel portfolio-slider custom-controls">';
$after = '</div>';

if( $type == 'carousel' ){
$before = '<div class="carousel-gallery-wrapper"><div class="carousel-gallery custom-controls">';
$after = '</div></div>';
}

/**
 * If we found items, output the gallery.
  * $before and $after change depending on the gallery chosen.
 */
if ( $attachments ) : 

echo $before;

$arrayInformation = array();

    foreach( $attachments as $ID ){
        $attachment = get_post($ID);
        $attachment_description = $attachment->post_content; //Afficher la description
        $attachment_caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; //Afficher le caption
        $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title; //Afficher le titre

        $arrayInformation[$ID] = array("title" =>$attachment_title, "caption" =>$attachment_caption, "description" =>$attachment_description);

        //IF : Affichage sur certaines images
        //if($attachment_description != ''){
        //echo '<div class="item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolioslider' ) . '<div class="captionportfolio"><h1 class="titrecaption">' . $attachment_title . '</h1>' . $attachment_description . '</div></div>';
        //}// else {
        echo '<div class="item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolioslider' ) . '</div>';
        //}
    }
echo $after;

endif;
```

And I want to call the content of the variable into this file :

```
<div class="container inner">

<?php get_template_part('postformats/format', get_post_format()); ?>

<div class="divide30"></div>

<?php 

global $post;

$titrecat = get_the_title();
if( has_term( 'creation', 'portfolio-category' ) ) {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Création - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>'; 
print $arrayInformation[$ID]["description"];
}
else if( has_term( 'realisation', 'portfolio-category' ) ) {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Réalisations - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>';
print $arrayInformation[$ID]["description"]; 
}
else if( has_term( 'inspiration', 'portfolio-category' ) ) {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Inspiration - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>'; 
print $arrayInformation[$ID]["description"];
}
?>  
</div>
```

get_template_part('postformats/format', get_post_format()); refer to the first file of course

I can't put the $ID number into the second file, cause is variable, thanks for your precious help :)

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 
/**
* Make sure we can access post data easily.
*/
global $post;

/**
* Setup variables needed for the gallery
*/
$attachments = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ebor_portfolio_gallery_list', true );
$type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ebor_gallery_format', true );
$before = '<div class="owl-carousel portfolio-slider custom-controls">';
$after = '</div>';

if( $type == 'carousel' ){
$before = '<div class="carousel-gallery-wrapper"><div class="carousel-gallery custom-controls">';
$after = '</div></div>';
}

/**
 * If we found items, output the gallery.
  * $before and $after change depending on the gallery chosen.
 */
if ( $attachments ) : 

echo $before;

$arrayInformation = array();

    foreach( $attachments as $ID ){
        $attachment = get_post($ID);
        $attachment_description = $attachment->post_content; //Afficher la description
        $attachment_caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; //Afficher le caption
        $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title; //Afficher le titre

        $arrayInformation[$ID] = array("title" =>$attachment_title, "caption"       
=>$attachment_caption, "description" =>$attachment_description);

        echo '<div class="item">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolioslider' )   
. '</div>';
    }
echo $after;

endif;
?>

<div class="divide30"></div>

<?php 

$idimage = $attachment->ID;

$titrecat = get_the_title();
if( has_term( 'creation', 'portfolio-category' ) )  {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Création - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>'; 
print $arrayInformation[$idimage]["description"];
}
else if( has_term( 'realisation', 'portfolio-category' ) ) {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Réalisations - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>'; 
}
else if( has_term( 'inspiration', 'portfolio-category' ) ) {
echo '<p><span class="portfolio-title">Inspiration - </span>' . $titrecat . '</p>'; 
}
?>


</div>
```

Comment: By using them outside the loop after you've defined them inside the loop? What are you asking? `echo $attachment_title` will work fine?

Comment: Not work, cause after the loop end, the variable cease to exist

Comment: [**Not true**](https://eval.in/222354). Unless you use a function or another scope, then the variables will exist.

Comment: Not an other scope, no function, even if I call my variable directly after the loop ther is nothing, when I call it into the loop it's ok

Comment: Your code is called using `include()` from the `get_template_part()` function, so you need to move the loop into another file altogether.

Comment: I try, but it display always the same description, but I have a carousel with 4 images, and i have to call the description for each images

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_push in loop like

```
array_push($new_arr, $attachment_description );
```

so you can get assigned array outside loop also

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array where index is your $ID and the value is an array with information you want.

```
$arrayInformation = array();

foreach( $attachments as $ID ){
        $attachment = get_post($ID);
        $attachment_description = $attachment->post_content; //Display description
        $attachment_caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; //Display caption
        $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title; //Display title

        $arrayInformation[$ID] = array("title" =>$attachment_title, "caption" =>$attachment_caption, "description" =>$attachment_description)
}
```

Now you can get the values (for example if your ID is 1)

```
print $arrayInformation[1]["title"];
print $arrayInformation[1]["caption"];
print $arrayInformation[1]["description"];
```

Comment: It doesn't work because  : this is a carousel, with a wordpress galery. each carousel show more than 5 images. I need to call, for each images, the title and description. I edit my first answer, with the two files. I moved the loop into the second file. But i have to remove the [1] from print $arrayInformation[1]. It's dynamic. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I know it's dynamic, the id 1 was just an example of how to access the values... You could have made a query that get all ID of the images ( or any other ay to get then ) and then looped each one in arrayInformation

Comment: ok thanks, but I don't know I can do that lol. I try since early morning and I feel disappointed :/

Comment: I make the Query into the loop?

Comment: if a query is useful to get IDs, you need to do it before loop.

Comment: I update my answer, I don't know how to do that, possible to give me some clues? Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Please I need some help, I try but I can only display de first description under the slider. When I change the slide, the description don't change. The slider is the loop foreach, and I have to show the image description under this loop, but I can't get the current image ID of the slider. Please Help. THanks

Comment: I think i will declare attachment ID before loop, and then replace the key $ID by $ID->$attachmentid. I will try this

Comment: Don't work, I can't make the relation between two ID, please help I will become crazy and I have to finish this at 11:am...

Comment: if you var_dump($arrayInformation), what do you see?